# How to configure multi-user chat (mod_muc) for Ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I've found this: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-muc

And this: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/ejabberdctl/muc-admin/#prerequisite

What are the steps I need to do to setup MUC from a fresh install? mod_muc is already in the ejabberd.yml file, and so is mod_muc_admin. I've also added myself as an admin.

Here is my ejabberd.yml file:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-208:/opt/ejabberd/conf$ cat ejabberd.yml
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - ip-10-0-1-208.us-west-1.compute.internal
  - xmpp.ughstudios.com

loglevel: info

certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - daniel@xmpp.ughstudios.com

auth_method: [external]
extauth_program: /opt/ejabberd_auth_bridge.py
extauth_instances: 3
auth_use_cache: true

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@ip-10-0-1-208.us-west-1.compute.internal"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
      - allow: daniel
      - allow: david
        #access_create: all
    #access_persistent: all
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Comment: This was silently cross-posted at https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/discussions/3770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the steps I need to do to setup MUC from a fresh install?

Usually mod_muc is already configured and enabled by default. Of course, if ejabberd is installed in a remote server, you will need to setup DNS for the MUC service, similar to what you may want to do for any other services that have their specific domain, like pubsub.example.org

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to associate a DNS with MUC service?

Comment: For DNS configuration examples for XMPP servers, see https://prosody.im/doc/dns#subdomains